# Как сделать вечную привязку (snap) в Inkscape?

Tags: svg, inkscape

[image]

концы линии привязаны к центрам кругов. Как делать так, чтобы при смещении кругов смещалась и соединяющая их центры линия?

**UPD (после первого ответа)**. Круги смещаются по отдельности: один круг смещается, и конец линии, привязанный к нему, смещается вместе с ним. Другой конец линии вместе с другим кругом остаётся на месте.

Comment: не надо править вопрос, когда уже дан ответ, вы ставите отвечающего в смешное положение. Надо внизу неправильного вопроса сделать пометку Update и там уточнить вопрос.

Comment: UPD. = пометка Update

Comment: вам был уже дан ответ в комментариях, что без скриптовых языков  вопрос в новой редакции не решить. Зачем вы убираете теги.

Comment: inscape — это некая программа, позволяющий создавать и редактировать svg-файлы, в которую может быть встроен любой алгоритм aka скрипт. Не вижу никаких причин, почему принципиально невозможно для перемещаемого объекта проверять все snap и прикреплённые точки перетягивать с объектом. Может есть какой-то хак или расширение. А если даже и нет, то в любом случае меня не интересует сам скрипт. Юзкейс: набросать в редакторе пару десятков необходимых объектов, сразу соединить их линиями, и затем, перетягивать объекты, чтоб-оно-выглядело-красиво, без необходимости пересоединять объекты линиями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Inkscape с версии 0.91 или 0.92 есть инструмент для рисования соединительных линий (`Ctrl+F2`). Попробуйте с его помощью, правда, соединятся не центры окружностей, а их края. Но есть трюк: в центре каждой окружности сделайте очень маленькую окружность такого же цвета или с прозрачной заливкой. Соедините маленькие окружности соединительной линией. Сгруппируйте попарно маленькие окружности с большими. Теперь, визуально, линия соединяет центры окружностей и движется вместе с каждой из них.

Comment: инструмент "Create diagram connectors" в самом низу списка инструментов, я его почему-то не заметил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Для этого надо объединить два круга и линию в одну группу

Рисуете в редакторе два круга, заполняете из цветом, далее рисуете линию соединяющую центры кругов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее нажав <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> делаете выделение всех объектов и объединяете их в группу нажав на иконку (показана красной стрелкой) или просто нажимаете <kbd>CTRL+G</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё объекты одно целое и их можно перемещать по холсту, как одно целое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код svg этих фигур

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 600" > 
 <g id="groupCircle"> 
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="red"/>
     <circle cx="300" cy="100" r="50" fill="blue"/> 
 <polyline stroke="black" stroke-width="3px" fill="black"
  points=" 100,100 300,100" /> 
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: похоже я неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Круги перемещаются не вместе, а по отдельности. Один круг смещается, и нода, привязанная к нему, смещается вместе с ним. Другая нода линии вместе с другим кругом остаётся на месте.

Comment: @yalov то есть должна длина линии изменяться?

Comment: да, поведение как у стрелки в каких-нибудь редакторах блок-схем

Comment: @yalov в векторном редакторе это сделать невозможно, только svg+js